# How to Mock IMessageReceiver?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, servicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

Currently i have scenario where i need to unit test a Service Bus Trigger Function. Fa code as below

```
public async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger("sample", Connection = "sample", IsSessionsEnabled = false)] Message message, IMessageReceiver messageReceiver, ILogger _log)
        {
           
//Some code
        }
```

I was primarily using `MessageReceiver`, but it's hard to unit test as it's not much flexible to Mock,so i switched to `IMessageReceiver`. Getting below Error

```
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Can't bind parameter 'messageReceiver' to type 'Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.IMessageReceiver'.
```

NB:- It have a Weird issue that the variable name should be **messageReceiver**, while using MessageReceiver .

Is there anything that i need to follow for **IMessageReceiver** as well?

Comment: Could you another name, e.g. "myReceiver". it could be that there is a `messageReceiver` property already defined somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

As of today, `IMessageReceiver` is not supported via dependency injection. You can only get `MessageReceiver`. You can upvote the request to add the support [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-servicebus-extension/issues/124).

Meanwhile, there's a workaround that you could use, showed [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-servicebus-extension/issues/69#issuecomment-668627650). The workaround is to have an additional, internal method, accepting `IMessageReceiver` and Function call that is injected `MessageReceiver` to pass the parameter to the internal method.